# How can I remove dependancies that are non existent or not being called on by any document?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, reactjs

I'm getting a console log 404 error that states missing css resources, when these files are not being required or used anywhere. Another strange thing is that the error reference is coming from where I am including jQuery. I know jQuery isn't calling for those CSS files. Can anyone help me figure out how to get rid of the errors and at the same time remove the attempt to load these documents?

[Here](http://three-d-slides.herokuapp.com/create) is a link to the live site!

Here is an image of the errors.[image]

Here is the code for the HTML doc so that you can see those files aren't being added into the Document.

```
<html class="" lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="assets/images/favicon.ico" type="image/png">
    <title>3D-SLIDES - Present your HTML and or Markup slides in a 3D Universe.</title>
    <link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nothing+You+Could+Do" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="assets/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/theme.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/uikit/css/uikit.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/codemirror/lib/codemirror.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="assets/plugins/uikit/css/components/htmleditor.css">
  </head>

    <!-- BEGIN BODY -->
    <body class="sidebar-collapsed color-default bg-lighter fixed-sidebar theme-sdtl ">
      <section style="opacity: 1;">


        <div id="appContainer"></div>


        </section>


        <!-- BEGIN PAGE SCRIPTS -->
    <script src="assets/plugins/jquery/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/uikit/js/uikit.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/codemirror/lib/codemirror.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/codemirror/mode/markdown/markdown.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/codemirror/addon/mode/overlay.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/codemirror/mode/xml/xml.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/codemirror/mode/gfm/gfm.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/marked/lib/marked.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/plugins/uikit/js/components/htmleditor.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
        <script src="assets/plugins/jquery-cookies/jquery.cookies.js"></script> <!-- Jquery Cookies, for theme -->
        <!-- END PAGE SCRIPTS -->

    <!-- REACT SCRIPTS -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./dest/bundle.js"></script>
        <script type="text/jsx">

        var slides = React.createElement(SlidesCreator);
        React.render(slides, document.body);

        </script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = function () {
            if(document.cookie) {
                document.cookie = '<div class' +'=; expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';
            }
            // console.log(document.cookie);
        }
        </script>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Awesome... Thanks again! You can also delete these comments if you want :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If not already done, make sure so that you don't include the css files from another one using [`@import`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@import).